# Rounding INT to make it 0 decimal places

Tags: swift

I am running the following code with a round function.

```
let percentage = round((progress / maxValue) * 100)
```

However it keeps returning numbers like: 15.0, 25.0, 35.0 etc.

I want it to return: 15, 25, 35, basically 0 decimal places.

How can I do this?

Cheers! :D

Comment: let percentage = Int(round((progress / maxValue) * 100))

Comment: Thank you young chap Adolfo! *in a British accent* :D It worked perfectly!

Comment: All correct answers guys! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast it to an Int:

```
let percentage = round((progress / maxValue) * 100)
let percentageInt = Int(percentage)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because round() returns a floating point number, not an integer:

[image]

If you want an integer, you have to convert it:

```
let percentage = Int(round((progress / maxValue) * 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

`round()` returns a floating point number. You can convert the result
to an `Int`, or call `lrint` instead:

```
let percentage = lrint((progress / maxValue) * 100)
```

The functions

```
public func lrintf(_: Float) -> Int
public func lrint(_: Double) -> Int
```

return the integral value nearest to their argument as an *integer*.